# Redirect to Web API FileStreamResult from MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, filestreamresult

I am trying to redirect from my MVC application to a FileStreamResult in my web api.  The MVC side needs to do a post because of the data that is being sent over.  The basic idea is that I should be able to post in the MVC side and what happens next is the API side will create the file and allow me to download/view from there.  With what I have it makes the request to the API side but stays on the MVC side.  My approximate code is below, any thoughts?

MVC

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(int id)
    {
        var body = GetBodyForPost(id);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, body);
            return response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

API

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Download")]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Download([FromBody] IEnumerable<RequestData> data)
    {
        var stream = BuildFileFromData(data);

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=print.pdf");

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: In the code above you are returning "OK" to the browser from the MVC action. The status code you're setting on the response from your API call is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks.  I realized what was in my MVC part wasn't really working and I updated it.  Still get the same result but it hits the API.